# OpenCobol compiler switch to allow duplcate data/paragraph names

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Does anyone know of an OpenCobol compiler switch to allow using the same name for both a data item and a paragraph.

I'm experimenting with version 1.1 and trying to migrate code from our AcuCobol (Now Micro-Focus Extend) dialect programs.

Our current compiler allows paragraphs to have the same name as data items, and there are quite a few examples in our code.

I'd prefer a way to just ignore the duplicates rather than having to hunt out every example and changing them.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this question on the [OpenCobol Q/A fourm](http://www.opencobol.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=1430&forum=1). You need to register and post questions on their proxy site (http://forum.peoplecards.ca). Hope the rest of your conversion goes well.

Comment: Updated information.  forum.peoplecards.ca was retired due to robot spam, and opencobol.org is dormant for the same reason. The OpenCOBOL project is now housed at SourceForge at [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/)  opencobol.org will eventually be replaced, in the magical _someday_ as it's a volunteer effort.